# xcodebuild - 'Code Sign error: Provisioning profile X can't be found'

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild, ios-provisioning, provisioning-profile

Yet another code sign error.

I'm running command:

```
xcodebuild -project $DIR/myproject.xcodeproj -sdk iphoneos5.0 -alltargets
```

and my project.pbxproj

```
"CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY[sdk=iphoneos*]" = "iPhone Distribution: Ryan"
"PROVISIONING_PROFILE[sdk=iphoneos*]" = "/Users/ryan/12345678-9012-3456-7890-123456789012.mobileprovision";
```

with output

```
=== BUILD NATIVE TARGET myproject OF PROJECT myproject WITH THE DEFAULT CONFIGURATION (Release) ===
Check dependencies
[BEROR]Code Sign error: Provisioning profile '/Users/ryan/12345678-9012-3456-7890-123456789012.mobileprovision' can't be found
```

I can't find any guidance on how to do this. Ive tried putting the provision in ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles and setting the profile field in project.pbxproj to just the profile ID

It is a requirement that I need to be configure this at the command line w/o Jenkins/Hudson

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Provisioning file goes to ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles and you you can select the provisioning profile like this:

```
xcodebuild PROVISIONING_PROFILE=12345678-9012-3456-7890-123456789012
```

Comment: This is a much better way of doing it. All the build flags that can be used are here: [https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html)

Comment: My provisioning profiles are in another user directory and jenkins run with a different user. Should I create the MobileDevices directory?

Comment: @Claus xcodebuild will look for the Provisioning files in that directory only. So you will need to copy them to ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles

Comment: If you have a provisioning file and want to get its id you can use: `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Print UUID' /dev/stdin <<< $(security cms -D -i ${WORKSPACE}/FILE.mobileprovision)`